# Where do I add a jQuery UI in Drupal 7?

Tags: views, theming, javascript

I have a view where I want to use the jQuery UI slider.
For the moment, I've just put the following in my template.php:

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.slider');
```

This doesn't feel right.

Is there a better place to put something like that, or at least do a check so it only get loaded when it is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you can use preprocess functions for views.

1. [Drupal 6 - Add Javascript to a View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129189/drupal-6-add-javascript-to-a-view)
2. [Programmatically set a css class of a view](http://drupal.org/node/930002#comment-3524258)
3. [Using views preprocesses to add css and js to a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892470/using-views-preprocesses-to-add-css-and-js-to-a-view)